# Drive API Update:

Tags: api, google-drive-api

I use the following API call (with a valid key) and it has stopped working for one folder but still works for another. When it doesn't work I get an empty "files": [] response rather than a error. I can see that the update has impacted the folder that doesn't work but I don't understand why as they both look the same. I have tried appending &resourcekey=yyy but it makes no difference.

What can I do to fix the problem in either the Drive UI, the API credentials, or in the API call?

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%270B6Gv6UcT0j6HY2VKbzktd2F1Z2M%27+in+parents&spaces=drive&fields=files(mimeType%2Cid%2Cname%2CthumbnailLink%2CimageMediaMetadata%2Cdescription)&key=xxx

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If its just returning an empty response then that's technically not an error.  Its telling you that there are no files in that directory.   Or in this case there are no public files in that directory as you are using an API key the directory must be public.    If the directory was not public you would be getting a 404 error.

Comment: Agreed, and this is what is confusing. The folder has files in it, and has been working for years before the update. The folder is public to those with the link in the same way as the uninpacted folder - I can't see why 1 still works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to pass the following HTTP header:

```
X-Goog-Drive-Resource-Keys
```

along with your request, and set its value to:

```
[FOLDER_ID]/[FOLDER_RESOURCE_KEY]
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem. Crazy that google A) couldn't articulate that, B) return a helpful error, C) use a rest parameter rather than a header value

Comment: Glad I could help.  Couldn't agree more on all points, especially on the returned error (or lack thereof).  In my case, I got a 200 HTTP status returned with the empty files array, which tricked me into believing I had no authentication issues, so I spent an inordinate amount of time looking elsewhere.